# How to query lucene for 2 index fields?

Tags: java, lucene

I'd like to execute queries with `lucene`. But the lookup should not only be based on the input, but also on a 2nd parameter.

Example: imagine the lucene index should contain `citynames` and `countrycodes`.

Now, during lookup I already know which country the desired cityname should be in.
SO I want to query the lucene index by cityname, but tell lucene to only look on the citynames where the countrycode matches.

It it possibel? If yes, how?

For a single attribute I would just set up the following:

```
QueryParser q = QueryParser(Version matchVersion, String f, Analyzer a)
Query q = queryParser.parse(input);
```

But how for 2 attributes?

Comment: Can you explain what would be wrong with simple `+cityname:SomeCity +countrycode:SomeCountryCode`?

Comment: I don't want to construct the query string myself, but define the queryparser that will finally generate that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Untested but you should get the idea:

```
String countryCode = ....;  // known in advance
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(matchVersion, f, a);
Query cityNameQuery = queryParser.parse(inputWithCityName);
Query countryCodeQuery = queryParser.parse("+countrycode:" + countryCode);

BooleanQuery result = new BooleanQuery();
result.add(new BooleanClause(cityNameQuery, MUST));
result.add(new BooleanClause(countryCodeQuery, MUST));
```